# application dosen't read config server spring cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Im try to create a simple project with 2 application ( a simple rest app and a config-server app )
My config-server project is ok, because if I got http://localhost:9091/form-create/container I can see all vars from form-create.properties

but my application form-create is not getting properties from config-server

here is my bootstrap.properties in form-create project

```
spring.application.name=form-create
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:9091
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
```

pom.xml in form-create project

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.formcloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>ms-form-create</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ms-form-create</name>
    <description>Microservice to manage form creation</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
          </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MsFormCreateApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MsFormCreateApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? if I start my form-create application is starting on 8080 port and not getting properties from config server.

Comment: There should be some logging in the form create app about attempting to contact config server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to check two things:

1. Your maven dependencies. It looks like you've put them wrong, namely, if you're running cloud config client, why do you have a dependency for `spring-cloud-config-server`?

For Web and cloud config client the following list is sufficient:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

2. When you start the config server, are you sure that it indeed reads the configuration from the repository you've configured (git, file system, whatever)?
   In general it exposes REST API so you can `curl` the server to get the information even without starting the spring boot application

Try that and make sure that it works as expected. For example, read [this part of tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration#Querying). Note that you might have put the configuration for different profile or different branch, cloud config server can handle that, but you'll have to specify profile for example in the `bootstrap.properties`.

Comment: solved :) thank you @mark-bramnik. I just removed `spring-cloud-config-server` then worked.